# Resizing a texture (not sprite) in PIXI.js

Tags: resize, textures, sprite, pixi.js

I need some help.

By dynamic image delivery (by bandwith) I get different sizes of textures from my server. Every Texture knows to what size itself has to be upscaled after being received from the client, but Textures in Pixi are not capable of resizing itself. It's just possible to make a Sprite from it and draw it in different scale. The clou: The Images are part of an image sequence and that uses just one sprite. Every texture does trim/crop individually and is placed correct, but the physical size is still the downscaled one (75/50/25%).

[image]

Here you can see an example of the 25% texture and the desired scaling. That scaling needs to happen before re-trim and -crop is done, because these are correct!

So if anyone has an idea how to resize a pure texture, any help is appreciated!

Dom

Comment: Found a workaround: Calculated resize factor on image load, made trim/= resizefactor and let the sprite use the resizefactor to scale up the whole thing. so trim / resize * resize is correct again.

Comment: If this a good fitting answer, write it as an answer in this thread